# CoreOs VM getting deleted after shutdown on libvirt

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, libvirt, coreos, virt-manager

I installed CoreOs on libvirt using link https://coreos.com/docs/running-coreos/platforms/libvirt/. The VM is also showing inside Virtual Machine Manager and working fine. The problem is once I shutdown the VM using Virtual Machine Manager, the instance of CoreOS is getting deleted and not showing under Virt-Manager. Do I missing something or is it the default behaviour of CoreOS ? Please help.

Comment: How did you _create_ the VM? This should not happen normally.

Comment: I created the VM using link https://coreos.com/docs/running-coreos/platforms/libvirt/

Answer (score 1):

I do not have enough time to inspect documents you've shared.

But I need to tell you that it is the same situtation when you use `virsh create` command instead of `virsh define` command. So just better to define your kvm from .xml configuration.